# Can my program communicate with GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I want to make gdb-wrapper.
As you know, GDB has only CLI interface. but I hate debugging on CLI interface :(
So I want to made GUI-Wrapper that use GDB debugger.

Like a OllyDBG, Down-side shows memory dump, Right-side shows Register, and Left-side shows Disassembled code.

But to this works, My program, GUI Wrapper, can communicate with gdb. but I have no idea to communicate GDB without Pipe. (Communicating with pipe is not so good idea)

Is there no way to communicate with gdb?

Comment: Why is using a pipe (with gdb in MI mode) not ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends explains what to do, apparently ddd which i suggested earlier, uses outdated interface

Comment: He actually wants https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html, but I think your link also is a good idea, as there is a number of "wrappers" already available, including Eclipse & Netbeans.